# Magento 2: Admin is not receiving order confirmation email

Tags: magento2, order-email

I have a Magento Version 2.1.1 website but when customer buy some things I can receive email for the order but customer are receiving order purchase email 
admin is not receiving customer order email

kindly help me to solve my issue?

Comment: Are you working in localhost, or check if mail server is installed in the system

Answer (score 2):

By default, Magento doesn't send an email to Admin, it only sends to Customer.

To achieve Go to **Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales Emails**

In "Order" Tab, put Admin Email Id here

[image]

Comment: yes dear i did this still not receiving

Comment: Are you using Cron scheduler or not? make sure cron is working correctly, you can contact your hosting provider to verify and if does not exist ask them to create normally they help you with this !